# Limit of $\frac{\lambda}{\chi _{2Y}^{2}}$ as $Y \sim \textrm{Poisson}(n\lambda)$ and $\lambda\to\infty.$

Tags: poisson-distribution, convergence, chi-squared-distribution, credible-interval

There are the following lines in Casella & Berger on page 438, before the equation (9.2.22):

> ...,  write $$\lambda = \frac{\lambda}{\chi _{2Y}^{2}}\chi _{2Y}^{2}$$
> where $\chi _{2Y}^{2}$ is a chi squared random variable with $2Y$ degrees of freedom, and $Y \sim \textrm{Poisson}(n\lambda)$. Then, as $\lambda \to \infty $, $\frac{\lambda}{\chi _{2Y}^{2}} \to \frac{1}{2n}$, and ...  .

Can anyone please explain how exactly $\frac{\lambda}{\chi _{2Y}^{2}} \to \frac{1}{2n}$ as $\lambda \to \infty $?

**EDIT:**

Here, the purpose is to illustrate how the coverage probability of the credible set which was constructed using the posterior distribution of $\lambda$, $\textrm{gamma}\left(a+\sum x,[n+\frac{1}{b}]^{-1}\right)$ behaves as $\lambda \to \infty$. Here is the screenshot of the passage from the book from google books.
[image]

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I edited the post and added the actual passage from the book and some details on $\lambda$

Comment: For large $\lambda,$ a Poisson $n\lambda$ variable becomes concentrated around its mean of $n\lambda.$  Because the expectation of a $\chi^2_{2n\lambda}$ variable is $2n\lambda,$ the division yields $\lambda/(2n\lambda) = 1/(2n)$ to an arbitrarily good approximation as $\lambda$ grows.  With this idea in mind, it's a routine application of mathematical technique to construct a rigorous demonstration if you need one.

Comment: The book should clarify the convergence mode.  I guess it means "$\lambda/\chi_{2Y}^2 \to 1/(2n)$ in probability.

Comment: Besides, the statement "*where $\chi_{2Y}^2$ is a chi squared random variable with $2Y$ degrees of freedom*" sounds very weird, because if you call $X$ a "chi squared random variable", then the degrees of freedom of it must be a non-random number.  At best, the loose symbol "$\chi_{2Y}^2$ needs to be interpreted as a compound Poisson process $\sum_{i = 1}^{2Y} X_i$, where $X_i \text{ i.i.d. } \sim \chi_1^2$.  In this case, the author also needs to state that $Y$ and $\{X_i\}$ are independent. Overall, a very confusing notation and writing.